# PHP form validation not functioning correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm having a little problem with my contact form. I think I got everything right but I always get the same wrong result.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['contact_message'])) {
        $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];

        if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_message)) {
            echo '0K!';
        } else {
            echo 'Every field is required.';
        }
    }
?>          
        <form action="contacts.php" method="POST">
            Nome:<br><input type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="25"><br><br>
            Email:<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="50"><br><br>
            Mensagem:<br>
            <textarea name="contact_message" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

When I fill all the fields I get the same result 'Every field is required.' when it should show 'OK!'. But I know all the fields received what I wrote, because I tested earlier.

I know it's a basic problem but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think your conditions are contradicting themselves.

Comment: The outer `if` should probably be just `if ($_POST) {` - it seems you are checking for completeness in the inner `if`.

Comment: but that way, i will not be able to know if the user filled the all fields correctly

Comment: (If you wish to speak to someone here, prefix their username like so: @halfer. I don't have to, since you are always notified of comments on your own posts). I think I've spotted your problem, hang on...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];

    if (empty($contact_name) && empty($contact_email) && empty($contact_message)) {
        echo 'Every field is required.'; //This would be the message if the field(s) are empty.
    } else {
        echo 'OK!'; //This would be the message if all the fields are filled in.
    }
}
?>          
    <form action="contacts.php" method="POST">
        Nome:<br><input type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="25"><br><br>
        Email:<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="50"><br><br>
        Mensagem:<br>
        <textarea name="contact_message" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: `!empty` means `NOT empty`

Answer (score 1):

The error was: `!empty($contact_mensagem)`(the message has been edited by halfer), but you actually have `$contact_message`.
I've tried the code on my computer and it worked:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['contact_message'])) {
        $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];

        if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_message)) {
            echo '0K!';
        } else {
            echo 'Every field is required.';
        }
    }
?>          
        <form action="contacts.php" method="POST">
            Nome:<br><input type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="25"><br><br>
            Email:<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="50"><br><br>
            Mensagem:<br>
            <textarea name="contact_message" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `if` is redundant. These will only be set during a POST operation, but they will be set for every POST regardless of whether they are complete, since your form elements will always provide a value. So, just use this:

```
if ($_POST) {
```

Next, read your values in a way that does not raise a warning if the index does not exist:

```
$contact_name = isset($_POST['contact_name']) ? $_POST['contact_name'] : null;
$contact_email = isset($_POST['contact_email']) ? $_POST['contact_email'] : null;
$contact_message = isset($_POST['contact_message']) ? $_POST['contact_message'] : null;
```

You can then test trivially like so:

```
if ($contact_name && $contact_email && $contact_message) {
     // ok
}
```